# GridView is so slow

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I'm filling a GridView with a BaseAdapter but it's so slow when scrolling. What can be the problem? It fills with two `imageViews` + a `textView`.

Thank you in advance.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    RowHolder rowHolder = null;
    View itemView = convertView;
    final ThemeModel curTheme = getItem(position);

    if (itemView == null) {

        rowHolder = new RowHolder();

        itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_themes_grid_row, parent, false);
        rowHolder.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        rowHolder.imageView2 = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        rowHolder.textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        itemView.setTag(rowHolder);

    }  else {
        rowHolder = (RowHolder) itemView.getTag();
    }

    rowHolder.textView.setText(curTheme.getThemeName());

    //Log("curTheme name = " + curTheme.getThemeName() + " / mainBg = " + curTheme.mainBg);



    if(curTheme.hasBgImage()) {

     // grid view item background image
      rowHolder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(curTheme.getMainBgImageId(Themes.this)); 

        //Picasso.with(Themes.this).load(drawable).into(rowHolder.imageView);
    } else {

    // grid view item background color
                  rowHolder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(curTheme.mainBg));
        //Picasso.with(Themes.this).load(Color.parseColor(curTheme.mainBg)).into(rowHolder.imageView);
    }

    if(curTheme.isUsing()) { //tick icon
        rowHolder.imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    else {
        rowHolder.imageView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    rowHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(!curTheme.isUsing()) //can cause error..
                chooseTheme(curTheme);
        }
    });

    return itemView;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have enough information about images that you are setting to imageView but the problem is probably because of their size. You can scale them before applying to view.

```
Drawable bgDrawable = null;

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    bgDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(curTheme.getMainBgImageId(Themes.this), null);
} else {
    bgDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(curTheme.getMainBgImageId(Themes.this));
}

//Scale the images
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) bgDrawable).getBitmap();
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(
               getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
               bitmap.getWidth() / 4,
               bitmap.getHeight() / 4,
               true)
          );

rowHolder.imageView.setBackground(drawable);
//You can use picasso
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) it is having smooth scrolling and better response than GridView.

Answer (score 0):

there might be different things..

1. Is the size of your imageviews fixed in the layout? Is the size of the parent depending on the size of the image which is loaded in the imageview?

If yes, this will slow down your view because everytime a new image is loaded the whole layout has to be adapted.

2. If the images are larger than the imageview, you should sample the pictures down in a background thread.